# Using a LCA110 DIP-6 Solid State Relay to switch 330v DC

Tags: arduino, capacitor, relay, solid-state-relay, coil

Would a LCA110 DIP-6 solid state relay work for switching 330v DC? I cannot find information on the datasheet of whether or not this is suitable for switching 330 volts DC. I am using it to switch 5 80uf 330v capacitors into a coil for a coilgun, using an Arduino.

Answer (score 4):

It's right there at the top of the DS: -

[image]

However, If you think it's going to survive your application I'd think again. Here's the hint - look at the load current.

Comment: And the on-resistance may be a problem for this application...

Comment: @BrianDrummond that might be the only thing that saves it!

Comment: Doubt it ... 330V, 35 ohms, call it 10A, 3kw. Subtract a guess for the coilgun inductors and it's still worth filming for Youtube...

Comment: Yeah I was only joking. It's dead in the water!

Comment: I actually did get it to work, ended up using 400v 10A relays which worked great. No video of smoking SSRs sadly

Comment: @Potatowarrior13 well done.